# Reversing the Master-Detail connection in Delphi

Tags: database, delphi, tadotable

I have 2 tables which are connected using master-detail connection. I need the connection reversed on creation of Form2 - so the master table becomes the detail table, and the detail table becomes the master table.

I tried doing this, and the program compiles, but doesn't work the way I want it to (the previous connection breaks, but it's not reversed, so the program kinda works like the tables aren't connected at all):

```
    Form1.ADOTableDetail.MasterSource.Destroy;
    Form1.ADOTableMaster.MasterSource :=  Form1.DataSourceDetail;
    Form1.ADOTableMaster.MasterFields := 'the_field_that_connects_them';
```

Any ideas on how I might achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't destroy the MasterSource!

In order to break the relationship do

```
Form1.ADOTableDetail.MasterSource:= nil;
Form1.ADOTableDetail.MasterFields:= '';
```

than use this to reroute the MasterDetail

```
Form1.ADOTableMaster.MasterSource :=  Form1.DataSourceDetail;
Form1.ADOTableMaster.MasterFields := 'the_field_that_connects_them';
```

Also never call `.Destroy` directly, use `.Free` instead.
Free does an extra check to see if the reference you are `Free`ing is not nil, preventing some Access Violations.

Comment: @Radiant, thanks for re-accepting my answer, you seem torn between the two :-). *Damn now I've got that annoying song in my head*.

Comment: Hehe. No problem. Yes, I really was torn between which one I should accept - it's the hard part of being a StackOverflow user :D

Anyways, I accepted your answer again, because NGLN's code gave me false sense of security. It could swap the relations only once, which I didn't notice. In the end I endedup writing my own sucky version of the code.

I thank you both again, though! :D

Answer (score 3):

```
procedure TForm1.ExchangeMasterDetail;
begin
  ADOTableDetail.Close;
  ADOTableMaster.Close;
  ADOTableMaster.MasterFields := ADOTableDetail.IndexFieldNames;
  ADOTableMaster.IndexFieldNames := ADOTableDetail.MasterFields;
  ADOTableDetail.IndexFieldNames := '';
  ADOTableDetail.MasterFields := '';
  ADOTableDetail.MasterSource := nil;
  ADOTableMaster.MasterSource := DataSourceDetail;
  ADOTableDetail.Open;
  ADOTableMaster.Open;
end;
```

Comment: Wow I tried this one now, and it's actually more flexible! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just set the **Master** table `Active` propriety to `false`.

Then do what you wanna todo and set it back to `true`.